# Error using boost::from_block_range on member dynamic_bitset, but not on local dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, boost-dynamic-bitset

I am attempting to convert a `std::vector<uint8_t>` into a `boost::dynamic_bitset`. I can achieve the inverse of this using the following code, where `values` is a class member function defined as
`boost::dynamic_bitset<uint8_t> values`.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> payload;
boost::to_block_range(values, std::back_inserter(payload));
```

However, I can't figure out how to do the inverse of it. The following compiles:

```
void MyClass::decode(std::vector<uint8_t> payload) const
{
    boost::dynamic_bitset<uint8_t> bits(payload.size() * 8);
    boost::from_block_range(payload.begin(), payload.end(), bits);
}
```

If I replace the `bits` local scoped-variable with the `values` class member variable (which from all indications are the same exact type, `boost::dynamic_bitset<uint8_t>`), I get the following compiler error:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘from_block_range(std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator, std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator, const boost::dynamic_bitset<unsigned char>&)’ boost::from_block_range(payload.begin(), payload.end(), values);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `decode` method is marked `const`, but you are attempting to modify class member variable `values`.

Either remove the `const` or mark `values` `mutable`

[For example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uNhJbB69LYXnkWSu):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include "boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp"

struct foo
{
    void do_the_thing()
    {
        std::vector<uint8_t> payload{1, 2, 3, 4};
        bits = boost::dynamic_bitset<uint8_t>(payload.size() * 8);
        boost::from_block_range(payload.begin(), payload.end(), bits);
    }
    
    boost::dynamic_bitset<uint8_t> bits;
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.do_the_thing();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I try to use const as much as possible out of habbit, this was a silly error on my part.